# Display parent and child node of a particular node by querying in OrientDB

Tags: sql, orientdb, graph-databases, graph-traversal

I tried querying using 'select' and 'traverse' function in OrientDB. Result is shown in the browse tab but I want it to get reflected on the graph as well. I want that part of the graph to be highlighted or something. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer you are looking for is this one

```
select expand(both()) from user where username = 'mitchken'
```

This will provide my own user and all edges starting from me going in or out.